# SqlFunctions wrapper

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, sql-function

I want to use `SqlFunctions.StringConvert()` in many places in different projects in my solution.

I dont want each project to hold reference to `system.data.entity` so I decided to put a wrapper in my `Common` project (all other projects has reference to `Common`).

How can I write such wrapper? If I am doing:

```
public static class SqlUtils
{
    public static Func<decimal?, string> StringConvert()
    {
        return x => SqlFunctions.StringConvert(x);
    }

    public static Func<double?, string> StringConvert()
    {
        return x => SqlFunctions.StringConvert(x);
    }        
}
```

Then I cannot use it like:

```
query.Where(x => SqlUtils.StringConvert((decimal)x.SerialNumber).Contains(serialNumber));
```

because entity framework don't know the method SqlUtils.StringConvert.

Any ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want EF to be able to translate it all down to SQL, you have to more work, see: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2010/01/01/defining-custom-functions-in-entity-framework.aspx

Comment: I want to use SqlFunctions and not custom functions.

Answer (score 0):

you can wrap the functions like as follows, but I don't think it meaningful:

```
public static class SqlUtils
{
    public static string StringConvert(double? x)
    {
        return SqlFunctions.StringConvert(x);
    }

    public static string StringConvert(decimal? x)
    {
        return SqlFunctions.StringConvert(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the EF will know how to use them??

Comment: of course, these two methods are with different signature(different arguments). This has nothing to do with the EF

Comment: @ojlovecd - SqlFunctions are EF extensions that EF understands and can compile directly down to SQL. Creating a utility class like this means that EF wont understand anymore how to compile this down to SQL.

Comment: @Polity: How can I create this utility without custom functions?

Comment: @Naor - See my answer. There is no real way for now to teach EF how to analyze your own functions unfortunatly. I quess you have to stick with holding references or create your own set of functions (for that again see my answer)